# How to avoid answering already client-cached data with GraphQL?

Tags: caching, graphql

**Hi everybody, please pardon my english :-)**

I have a JS client that request data with GraphQL and store them.

It happends that GraphQL request ask for data that already are cached on the client, and I'm looking for a way to avoid resending them.

## Example

- Authors may have books
- A first query ask for the 20 Lasts books (for main page for example)
- A second query ask for the books of a precise author

This is a probably an example of unnecerary cache usage due to the small amount of data, but it shows the problematic.

## Potential ways

- Use server cache as answered here: [How does caching work in GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48919586/4032282)
- Send already client-cached data id with the request to allow the server to not join this data with the answer if still valid - But how to do that ?
- Create a "request id" and let the server know if data have evolved depsite the last query - It seems to be heavy for the server...

**Thank you in advance for your(s) answer(s) !**

Comment: If I understand you example correctly you want to not return a part of a list when you already fetched some of it. That is very difficult to do and I urge you to check if you aren't optimising what isn't slow enough to optimise. If you talk about the phenomenon where you have an object in the store and you confidently mirror the server implementation check out [cache redirects](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/cache-updates.html#cacheRedirect) in Apollo Client. (e.g. you could try and answer `book(id: $id)` in you example easily)

Comment: I dont have a practical case that need this optimisation now, but Im dealing with a project that may need caching so Im evaluating the differents possibilities (REST, GraphQL, ...). Thank you for your links, I'll check them as soon as possible !